# Trying to Print C# Arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying print 3 things in straight line like name, age and wages.

like this

```
Graham 47 500

Jess   47 250

Dave   23 100
```

type here

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace General_Employee_Data
{
    class Program
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        var Namelist = new string[2, 2, 3]
        {

                { "Graham", "47", "500" },
                { "Jess" , "47", "250" },
                { "David", "23", "100" },
        };

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Namelist[i, i, i]);

            }

        }
    }
```

This isn't homework as I doing it to practise my C#, I seem made it more complex than simple.

I trying get arrays names, age , wages on the screen.

Comment: Instead of a multidimensional array, create an Employee class and use a List (or array) of that

Comment: However, what are your issues with the code? Please add any compiler and runtime error

Answer (score 3):

To print an array on single line, either you can print each element one by one, like

```
Console.WriteLine(Namelist[i][0] + "\t" +  Namelist[i][1] + "\t" +  Namelist[i][2]);
```

Or you can use `string.Join()` to convert string array to string,

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(@"\t", Namelist[i]));
```

---

I recommend creating a class instead of a string array to store all relevant fields.

```
public class Employee
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
   public int Wages { get; set; }


   public Employee(string name, int age, int wages)
   {
       this.Name = name;
       this.Age = age;
       this.Wages = wages;
   }

   //This will help you to convert, Employee object to expected string
   public override string ToString()
   {
      return $"{this.Name} \t {this.Age} \t {this.Wages}";
   }
}
```

Now store all details in `List<Employee>`, like

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>()
{
    new Employee("Graham", 47, 500),
    new Employee("Jess", 47, 250),
    new Employee("Dave", 23, 100)
}
```

Now whenever you want to print the detail, try below

```
foreach(var employee in employees)
    Console.WriteLine(employee);
```

---

To learn more about Classes, Constructor, ToString method read below links

- [Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/classes)
- [Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)
- [ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-7.0)

Answer (score 0):

what about converting it to a string and than printing it out like

```
Console.WriteLine(Namelist[i].ToString());
```